# OpenCart - Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on null error

Tags: error, opencart

The following is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on null in /home/ekopnnfa/public_html/shopping-mania.eu/catalog/view/theme/logancee/template/common/footer.tpl on line 2
```

The reference that is missing is the following one:

```
if($registry->has('theme_options') == true)
```

The version of OpenCart is the latest one, and the theme is supported under it.

Can someone please let me know how to add this `theme_options` in the registry, or generally how to fix the error?